# laravel query builder: join dependent on primary content

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, lumen

I'm using luman and [Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) to fetch full user info from database.

First, Please Take a lock at my database structure:
I have a table called `users` and a series of other tables that are related to user groups (Ex: `secretaries`, `patients`, `doctors` and `admins`) which stores additional information about the users.

Also To determine user access, I have a `level` column on `user` table which can have one of this value as enum: `'admin', 'doctor', 'secretary', 'patient'`.

So, I want to get this information using **one** query by `join` and `select`.

My training code is something like this:

```
$userInfo = User::where("userID", $userID)
           ->limit(1)
           ->join('[GROUP_TABLE_NAME]', function ($join) {
                  $join->on('user.userID', '=', '[GROUP_TABLE_NAME]' .'.'.
                                         '[GROUP_NAME]' . 'ID');
            })
            ->get();
```

The **`GROUP_NAME`** comes from `level` column on `user` table and the **`GROUP_TABLE_NAME`** can be built based on the **`GROUP_NAME`** value(Ex: `['secretary' => 'secretaries' , 'patient' => 'patients' , ...]`).

Any idea to handle the join structure using laravel query builder?

Comment: Have a look at polymorphic relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 0):

First you should be aware of the fact that this code architecture is not convenient and not easy to understand for other developers.

**SQL**
You can achieve your goal by using `union` and `join`.

Just convert this query for laravel builder or use it directly with `DB::statement`: `select users.*, infos.info from users left join (( select secretaries.* from secretaries ) UNION (select doctors.* from doctors)) infos ON users.id = infos.user_id where users.id=?`.

**But**

The easiest way to do it is to fetch info in two queries, both indexed and fast: user from `users` by primary key and then info by indexed field `user_id` in it. Create `Doctorinfo`, `Admininfo` models and correspondent migrations. So user class can be smth like this:

```
public function getInfo() {
    switch($this->level) {
        'doctor':
            return $this->doctorinfo;
         ...
    }
}

private function doctorinfo() {
    $this->hasOne('App\Doctorinfo');
}
```

**Builder**

You can use left join to join all sub tables as well. The following builder selects `info` column.

```
User::where("userID", $userID)->limit(1)
   ->leftJoin('patients', 'users.id', '=', 'patients.user_id')
   ->leftJoin('doctors', 'users.id', '=', 'doctors.user_id')
   ->leftJoin('admins', 'users.id', '=', 'admins.user_id')
   ->select('users.*', DB::raw('IF(users.level="admin", admins.info, (IF users.level="doctors", doctors.info, patients.info))'))
```